# Python Удалить ряды в датасете по условию

Tags: python, pandas, drop

Датасет: s

```py
kills_list = {
    name:"CSS для начинающих"
    period:1.0
    company:"Code Basics"
    CATEGORY:"CSS"
}
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 7457 entries, 0 to 7456
```

Мне нужно удалить всё строки из всех колонок датасета, если в колонке:

```
CATEGORY   . value_counts > 16 и < 1000
```

Я пробовала так:

```py
skills_list_cut = skills_list.drop(
    skills_list.map(lambda x: x.value_counts('CATEGORY')) > 16 < 1000)
```

Comment: А у нас есть вопрос, который можно удалить, потому что не видно попытки решить его самостоятельно.

Comment: skills_list_cut = skills_list.drop(skills_list.map(lambda x: x.value_counts('CATEGORY')) > 16 )

Comment: я так пыталась. Из этого и так видно, что я новичок

Comment: их этого ничего не видно. пример датасета приведите в вопросе (вы можете его редактировать) и код свой тоже в вопрос вставьте. все должно быть в текстовом виде. иначе вопрос будет закрыт. хотите помощи, сделайте так, чтобы мы могли вам помочь

Comment: и вообще странное условие. если что-то меньше 6, то оно явно и меньше 1000. вы точно все верно записали?

Comment: skills_list['counted_index'] = skills_list['CATEGORY'].value_counts()\
skills_list = skills_list_cut[(skills_list.counted_index >= 16) | (skills_list.counted_index <= 765)]           Попробовала так. Работает. Есть ли еще какой-то вариант без создания отдельной колонки?

Comment: Вы можете не в колонку, а в обычную переменную записать эти промежуточные данные.

Answer (score 0):

Пояснения в комментариях

```
skills_list = pd.DataFrame({'CATEGORY': [1000] * 17 + [900] * 16 + [5] * 25 + [3] * 7000 + [4] * 1000}) # генерируем данные

vc = skills_list.CATEGORY.value_counts()
vc = vc[vc.between(16, 1000, inclusive='neither')].index.to_list() # отбираем все строки с числами, количество которых находится в диапазоне от 16 до 1000, не включая границы
skills_list = skills_list[skills_list['CATEGORY'].isin(vc)] # отбираем строки исходного фрейма, содержащие отобранные ранее числа
print(skills_list)
```

Результат: во фрейме остались строки с числами 1000 и 5, поскольку 1000 повторяется 17 раз, а 5 повторяется 25 раз, т.е. кол-во повторов в диапазоне от 16 до 1000

```
    CATEGORY
0       1000
1       1000
2       1000
...
15      1000
16      1000
33         5
34         5
...
56         5
57         5
```

Comment: counted_index = skills_list['CATEGORY'].value_counts()\            nskills_list = skills_list[(counted_index >= 16) | (counted_index <= 765)]          записала в переменную, теперь выдает ошибку:  Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).

Comment: skills_list = skills_list[(counted_index.values >= 16) | (counted_index.values <= 765)]    так пишет, что в моей переменной меньше значений, чем в колонках датасета. Вобщем-то, поэтому я колонку и создавала. Что не так у меня?

Comment: @AnnaAstor все правильно пишет, в датасете больше строк, чем в `value_counts()`, потому что `value_counts()` - это агрегат колонки датасета. Они будут равны по длине только в том случае, если все значения в датасете уникальные. Для нагладности распечатайте датасет и `value_counts()` и сравните